# modelling multiplicative relationships with categorical data

Tags: scikit-learn, statistics, modeling

If I want to create a model that best describes the price of an asset using a multiplicative relationship, that is,

Price = base_rate * size_of_asset * number_of_subassets

(size of asset, number of subassets are both 0,1,2,3... N)

can I do this with a linear combination when the variables are categorical? If they were numerical I could log everything, which would do exactly that... however, the same approach can't be applied with categorical data, can it?

NB: I want to keep it as a multiplicative relationships so it's highly interpretable from a ratio perspective - that is, one can say by increasing the size_of_asset by 30% increases the price by x amount.

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think log-linear might be your solution as it can help you analyse the multiplicative effects of one or more categorical independent variables with a categorical dependent variable.

Check this out:

http://members.home.nl/jeroenvermunt/esbs2005c.pdf